# How many times have the team batting first declared innings and then lost the match by innings?

Tags: cricket, history, statistics, trivia

In the recently completed test match of [Aus Vs India](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india-v-australia-2013/engine/match/598813.html), Australia lost by an innings even after declaring their first innings. How many times have this happened in Test cricket? Are there any reference to any previous games in which the same happened?

Answer (score 4):

This is the first time in the Test match history that a team declared the first innings and lost the match by an innings.

Reference: From the article by Cricinfo: [Losing after a first-innings declaration](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india-v-australia-2013/content/current/story/623587.html)

> This is the [11th instance](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=1;event=2;filter=advanced;innings_number=1;orderby=start;result=2;template=results;type=team;view=results) of a team losing a Test after declaring in its first innings, **but the first in which the team declaring has lost by an innings**.